# How can the Zeta function be zero?

Tags: sequences-and-series, euler-product

> How can the Zeta function be zero?

If the zeta function is the Euler product:

$$\zeta(s)=\prod_p \frac{1}{1-p^{-s}}$$

Then being a product my first thought was that it could only be zero if one or more of its terms were zero.

This would require $\frac{1}{1-p^{-s}}$ to be zero for some prime $p$

So there would have to be some prime $p$ for which $p^{-s}$ is infinite.

Clearly I'm misunderstanding something.  Are the zeroes where the terms $(1-p^{-s})$ diverge?

Comment: When people speak of the zeta function, they refer to the analytic continuation of a function defined for Re$( s)>1$.

Comment: The Euler product $\prod_p \frac{1}{1-p^{-s}}$ as well as $\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{-s}$ both converge **only** for $\Re(s) >1$. For $\Re(s) > 0$, $\zeta(s)$ is given by $\frac{1}{1-2^{1-s}} \sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n+1} n^{-s}$ or $\frac{s}{s-1} +s \int_1^\infty (\lfloor x \rfloor-x) x^{-s-1}dx$ or many other [formulas](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RiemannZetaFunction.html)

Comment: First they're not *terms* , they're *factors*. Second, there's not a finite number of factors, so the limit of the finite products may very well be $0$, albeit each finite product is different from $0$.

Comment: How can a summation of infinite rational numbers sum up to an irrational number? Because we are taking a limit. Much like in your case, the factors never are zero, but keep getting closer and closer to zero, ergo is the limit.

Comment: *(This doesn't address the specific case of the Riemann zeta function, but is aimed at the OP's more general confusion around infinite products:)* An infinite product **can** be zero without any term being zero - remember that its value is the *limit* of the finite partial products. So think about $\prod_{k\in\mathbb{N}}{1\over 2^k}$: each finite partial product is nonzero (since each term is nonzero), but those finite partial products get arbitrarily small.

Comment: Let me clarify why this is inappropriate as an answer: while it does address the OP's "base" confusion, it doesn't answer the question "for what reason(s) can we have $\zeta(z)=0$?," since $\zeta$ is *not*, in fact, defined as an infinite product in general. It does, however, answer the underlying question of "how can an infinite product of nonzero terms be zero?."

Comment: @RobertFrost The analytic continuation of the function is not convergent, but it is based on the convergent half of the function. Understanding why a product that is nowhere zero suddenly becomes zero is essentially what's missing. Then, taking that result and using it in the non-analytic half is the next, obvious step.

Comment: @Bernard: (1) The terms $1 - p^{-s}$ are **not** the factors of the OP's product. (2) It is standard to consider an infinite product to diverge if the limit of the finite products is $0$.

Comment: @RobArthan/ Yes, they're the denominators of the factors. Sorry for the ellipsis.

Comment: Consider the product $1/10 \times1/10\times\cdots \times 1/10$. If you let the number of factors go to infinity, you get $0$ and none of the factors are zero.

Comment: (1/3) From an informal viewpoint: when you want to ask abut zeros of the Riemann Zeta function you need to know the theorems that say to you where has zeros the Riemann Zeta function $\zeta(s)$ and how is defined the Riemann Zeta function in the whole complex plane $\mathbb{C}$, or in some specific region. You need to check both conditions, see these informal examples: A) $\prod_p \frac{1}{1-p^{-s}}=0$ for some complex number with $\Re s>1$ is a contradiction because $\zeta(s)$ has no zeros in such region and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^s}=0$ for $0<\Re s<1$ is a contradiction because this

Comment: (2/3) Euler product doesn't converge in such region. B) Equate to $0$ the Mellin transform in $(11)$ of this [MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RiemannZetaFunction.html) for $0<\Re s<1$ is right because we met both conditions, there are zeros in this region (non-trivial zeros) and both sides of $(11)$ are well defined  (are convergent, since it is a theorem).

Comment: (3/3) C) Finally in this section of the [Digital Library of Mathematical Functions](http://dlmf.nist.gov/25.2) you've more representations for different regions of the complex plane, and if you equate to zero some of such representations you can to dilucidate when it has mathematical meaning. Good luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- The Euler product only converges for $\Re(s) > 1$.
- The Riemann hypothesis is that $$\phi(s) = \prod_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1-(k \log k)^{-s}}{1-p_k^{-s}}$$ converges for $\Re(s) > 1/2$ (it is easy to show it converges for $\Re(s) > 1$ and the prime number theorem is that it converges for $\Re(s) \ge 1$)
- That it converges means to an analytic function, ie. the series $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \log \frac{1-(k \log k)^{-s}}{1-p_k^{-s}}$ converges to an analytic function so that $\log \phi(s)$ is finite and $\phi(s)$ has no zeros.

  Since the analytic continuation of $\psi(s) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \log (1-(k \log k)^{-s})$ is known to have no zeros for $\Re(s) > 0$, it implies $\log \zeta(s)-\psi(s)$ and hence $\log \zeta(s)$ have no zeros for $\Re(s) > 1/2$
- That $\phi(s)$ converges for $\Re(s) > 1/2$ is equivalent to the number theoretic statement $$\pi(x) -\underbrace{ \sum_{2 \le k \le x} \frac{1}{\log k}}_{ = \ \text{Li}(x)+\mathcal{O}(1)} = \mathcal{O}(x^{1/2+\epsilon})$$

Comment: Thanks, this is all good stuff but the question asks how can it be zero.  I'm not sure you answer that.  Is it because the parts $(1-p_k^{-s})^{-1}$ become arbitrarily small like Noah says below?

Comment: @RobertFrost No. See a course on complex analysis and the links of mixedmath answer.  $2+\sum_{n=1}^\infty z^n$ converges only for $|z| < 1$, but writing it as $2+\frac{z}{1-z}$ shows its **analytic continuation** has a zero at $z=2$. This is exactly the same for $\zeta(s)$.

Comment: ok thanks. There's a lot of talk about convergence but I'm not seeing much about zeroes. It sounds like I need to better understand what it means for something's analytic continuation to have a zero,

Answer (score 7):

The Euler product only converges for $\mathrm{Re} (s) > 1$. For $\mathrm{Re} (s) \leq 1$, you need to consider a different representation of the zeta function.

The different representation comes from the "analytic continuation" of the zeta function. This has been written about extensively on this site. See for instance

1. [Riemann zeta function's analytic continuation](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2280029/9754)
2. [What exactly is the Riemann zeta function?](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1180438/9754)
3. [How are zeta function values computed in the critical strip](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1082139/9754) (which is where all the interesting zeroes are).

Comment: And the only way to *"see"* the non-trivial zeros is with the functional equation allowing to define the [real function $Z(t)$](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Riemann-SiegelFunctions.html) corresponding to $\zeta(1/2+it)$